# почему изображения при width:100%; css уменьшается пропорционально?

Tags: css, img

почему изображения при `width:100%;` css уменьшается пропорционально?

Comment: Скорее всего потому что размер внешнего блока меньше изображения

Answer (score 0):

Потому что для них так работает `height: auto`.

Если надо растягивать непропорционально, то надо явно указывать оба размера.

Comment: как задать такие свойства div?